$F$-vector space as an $FG$-module respects scalar product
I'm studying representation theory and the equivalence between $F$-representations of a group $G$ and $FG$-modules for a field $F$. I'm stuck at what seems like a little triviality: Consider a $F$-vector space $V$ that is also a $FG$-module. We ask that $ev = v \; \forall v \in V$ where $e$ is the neutral element in $G$.
Now, how can we prove that, for any $\lambda \in F$, $\lambda v$ is the same as $(\lambda e) v$. That is, does the scalar product work well between the group ring and the vector space?
We cannot immediately take the scalar out of the parenthesis, or at least I can't find any property of modules that allows us to do that. The properties of modules do let us do this if $\lambda$ is a positive integer (a sum of $1$s) or even a "positive rational". Maybe there's some more play with the properties that let us prove this for "roots of rationals", since we know that $(rs)v = r(sv) \; \forall r,s \in FG, v \in V$, but we would still have to work some more with irrational scalars if we consider fields like $F = \mathbb R$.
Am I missing something? It seems natural that $FG$-modules should work this way but I can't figure it out.

This has to come from the definition. We have $F\subseteq FG$ with the identification $\lambda\to \lambda e$. So when you write "$F$-vector space that is also a $FG$-module", there has to be a connection between the two. Precisely, if $V$ is a module over $FG$ then it can be turned into a vector space over $F$ by the action $\lambda v:=(\lambda e)v$. The scalar product has to come from the action of $FG$. Or if you wish, the action of $FG$ has to "extend" the action of $F$.
More generally, if $A$ is any algebra over the field $F$ then any module $V$ over $A$ becomes a vector space over $F$ by "restriction of scalars", i.e for $\lambda\in F, v\in V$ we define $\lambda v=(\lambda 1_A)v$. In this case, for any $a\in A$ we have:
$$\lambda (av)=(\lambda a)v=a(\lambda v). \ \ \ \ \ \ (*)$$
Note: Since the definition of an algebra already includes a scalar product, there is also an equivalent approach. Instead of considering the natural embedding $F\subseteq A$, we may just define a module over an algebra a bit differently from a module over a ring. We require $V$ to be an $F$-vector space (and not just an abelian group), and in addition to the usual module axioms we also require $(*)$ to hold.
If the algebra $A$ is unital then this approach is clearly equivalent to defining a usual module over the ring $A$ and then turning it into a vector space over $F$ by restricting scalars, like I described above. If we allow algebras without identity, we have no choice, we have to use the second approach. So in some sense, it is more universal.

yes these are my thoughts too. i've found other questions similar to mine that were answered by saying that the scalar product on the vector space is induced by the module structure, so it works out of the box
however, the version of the theorem for the representation and module equivalence that im studying fixes the vector space first and then says that the representations are in bijection to the $FG$-modules structures. I guess my question actually is if it is possible to create an $FG$-module structure that doesn't work well with a fixed scalar product?

@dino Well, if there are a few different scalar products that turn $V$ into an $F$-module then a fixed $FG$ action will not be compatible with at least one of them. Anyway, the theorem you are trying to prove doesn't have these issues. Given a representation of $G$ (in particular you have a fixed vector space), you can "extend" the action from $G$ to $FG$, and you obtain an $FG$-module. Conversely, given an $FG$-module, restricting the action to $F$ gives you a vector space, and restricting the action to $G$ gives a representation of the group in that space. These are inverse operations.

thank you. i've marked your answer as accepted
